# How Can I Connect Links In URL

Tags: php, html, sql

Some one please help me, I can't figure out how to display two connected links in url.Like I'm getting this:

```
http://localhost/Project/index.php
```

And when I click another link of same page I get:

```
http://localhost/Project/another.php
```

But what I want is:

```
http://localhost/Project/index.php/another.php
```

Comment: why would you want that? This sounds like an XY problem. What are you really trying to do, go through a front controller?

Comment: strange, why would you want that?

Answer (score 1):

This question is incorrect because **index.php** is a PHP file.
If you want to redirect your link to another.php. it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If one of your links is a childpage of the other, you can organise that:
- through your routes (referring to a frontcontroller for example).
- through your views (just provide the correct link of the file or name of the view that needs to be rendered).

What is the purpose or connection of those two links?
A bit more context explanation can maybe lead to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with standard servers/form, but if you connect a child element to one of these links and put it in another, you can get this as an outcome. If you don't want to do that, I suggest connecting links through **#** buttons. For example, if I clicked on a button with an outcome of #warning, #warning would be added to my URL with the following parent element. The child element in this case is the **#**.

*Parent > Child > #* also works, but it is highly unrecommended. Lastly, **#** only works if the button links to the same page. Make sure that your page element is stored in the **#**.